# Horizontal nav with CSS rollover

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

The rollover's uses one image for the hover. It's cool, but I don't know how to get it to work in a horizontal menu. What do I do?

```
<head>
<style>
/*CSS HOVER WITH ONE IMAGE*/
#emailUs{display: block;width: 107px;height: 23px;background: url("slide.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;}
#emailUs:hover{background-position: 0 -23px;}
#emailUs span{position: absolute;top: -999em;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--Trying to get three buttons to go across 'same button as example'-->
<a id="emailUs" href="#" title="Email Us"><span>Email Us</span></a>
<a id="emailUs" href="#" title="Email Us"><span>Email Us</span></a>
<a id="emailUs" href="#" title="Email Us"><span>Email Us</span></a>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

CSS SPRITE
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the css: "float:left;"

Once you set a link to "display:block;", it will automatically go to the next line after - so - making them float left will bring them back up into a horizontal line.

Also, you shouldn't have more than one element with the same id.  Use class instead for anything you'll need on more than one element.

Comment: Also, you can set background-position to top left, then bottom left instead of using specific numbers.  This will make it easier in the future if you decide to change the button size.

Comment: In case you've not used "float" much, you'll also need to put a div or something after your menu with "clear:both;" to make sure the next things in your code don't get pushed up underneath the floated menu.